# Is there a way to not have the new gmail Signature add "--" before it?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

Gmail now supports multiple rich-text signatures.  However it prepends "--" before the signature.  Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: The double-dash before the signature block is a long-standing standard in e-mail.

Comment: I wouldn't say long standing I would say antiquated.  Look at most professional signature blocks from large companies, double-dash is not included.

Comment: And I would suggest they're doing it wrong. For one, that convention allows e-mail clients to *not* included the signature block when quoting for a reply.

Comment: Interesting.  They seem to have another way of detecting signatures and graying them.  If you don't enable the Labs feature as Brian suggested than your signature gets turned into the purplish quoted text with the rest of the previous text... right or wrong, I like what the labs feature does better.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Yes**

In "General" settings, under the signature text box, check the check-box that says

> Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the
>   "--" line that precedes it.

Comment: Thank you!
"Signature tweaks
by Keith C and Dave C

Places your signature before the quoted text in a reply, and removes the "--" line that appears before signatures."

Comment: @drye: I was very pleased when I found it too :)

Comment: Totally skimmed over that line many many times. That settings page is sooooo cluttered these days. Thanks for mentioning this!