# How do I create a decent email signature in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-signature

I've recently signed up for Google Apps because of the email support. I only use the web based gmail client for all my mail. I'd like to have a professional email signature for each email that I send that includes a small image which is the Logo of my company. How can include such an signature with Gmail?

Comment: A lot of your recipients won't see the image anyway as most e-mail clients block the downloading of remote content (like images) by default.

Comment: I've learned to avoid the image as well, what you can do is add links to your social marketing sites, twitter, facebook, etc.

Comment: I came up with an approach I haven't seen elsewhere: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92327/122349 (Basically use Chrome Dev Tools to manipulate the HTML in the textarea)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google recently [announced](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/07/rich-text-signatures.html) support for rich text in signatures. That means you can now configure the font family, size and color, as well as insert images into the signature. Just go to your gmail settings and you'll find it right there, no need to enable as a lab feature or anything! It's possible it hasn't been expanded to Google Apps for your domain yet, in which case it should be coming pretty soon.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/TDYhaX9aJCI/AAAAAAAAAok/SUZMdB9N7sI/s1600/rich_text_signatures1.png))</sub>

Comment: I can confirm that my domain has this feature already, so it's certainly a matter of time before you get it (I have my language set to English [US]).

Comment: Remember to refer to this question to remove the "--" before the signature http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/is-there-a-way-to-not-have-the-new-gmail-signature-add-before-it

Comment: And this question, which could almost be a duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/how-to-add-an-image-to-my-gmail-signature

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to that if you have multiple accounts (and hence want multiple signatures) Gmail can now handle this too (I used to have to use 'labs' canned responses to do this). So if you also set up Gmail to automatically respond to the e-mail account the message was originally sent to it means you automatically get the correct signature on your reply. Very nice.