# Insert HTML markup into Gmail signature

Tags: gmail, email-signature

Is there any way to add HTML markup signature in Gmail settings? I mean, insert some HTML markup without using rich editor, just inserting HTML?

Comment: I came up with an approach I haven't seen elsewhere: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92327/122349 (Basically use Chrome Dev Tools to manipulate the HTML in the textarea)

Answer (score 9):

No, you're constrained to use the Rich Text editor.

See also: [How do I create a decent email signature in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3856/how-do-i-create-a-decent-email-signature-in-gmail)

Answer (score 5):

After nearly giving up, I finally figured out how. I used the Chrome Developer Tools, but you should be able to use any Dev WYSIWYG editor.

On the settings page where you have the option to use the Rich Text Editor for your signature, use the Dev Tools to inspect the text area. Now you can simply edit the HTML within the signature directly!

To get my work done even more quickly, I used the built-in signature tools to upload some images and insert some hyperlinks. I just used the Dev Tools to polish everything to pixel perfection.

Comment: Makes no sense. How will changing this code change the signature forever? What HTML/CSS are we editing this way, of the textarea in Gmail itself. I tried pasting my HTML from the sig which has a simple table, with colorisation of links. Didn't work.

Comment: @PKHunter Right-click on the Gmail signature text area and inspect it. I'll assume that you're using Chrome. In the Developer Tools, you should see a bunch of DIVs. One of them in the hierarchy should be `class="gmail_signature"`, but you can press F2 and edit any DIV at that level or lower and manipulate the HTML. After you finish making changes to your liking, go back to the actual settings page and trigger the onchange event. You can do this by simply adding a space or a character, then backspacing. The HTML that you manually edited will now be saved as your signature.

Comment: Nate, this is super helpful.

Comment: @PKHunter Thank you! I'm glad that my explanation cleared that up! = )

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible, though not, as far as I can see, by using the Gmail signature editor directly.

You can create the signature you want using a different tool (I use WiseStamp with Firefox which supports a 'better' HTML editor) then once defined, simply copy the result from the 'normal' view, not the HTML view, and paste it into the Gmail sig edit box.

You could, of course, use an addon such as WiseStamp to provide the Sig for you but I prefer not to use an addon where there is already a suitable builtin facility.

Using this method I've even been able to embed an image without having a URL to it, though it can fail because the Sig gets too big!

Comment: This is a sort-of-solution.  Problem is that, if you say, use css within the html to customize the *colours* of a links - those colours and formatting are completely lost in the gmail editor.  The gmail editor does not provide any way to colourize links.  You get a plain old blue-underlined link and that's it - no matter what you paste there.

Answer (score 1):

Create the template in your editor and view it in a browser.  Then in the browser, select all, copy and paste into the Gmail compose window and save.  This worked for me.

Comment: Works for simple stuff. Not for a slightly cleaner HTML with, say, a table.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an incredible easy way here: http://myhtmlsignature.com/how-to-install-an-email-signature-in-gmail/

1. Create an html file like signature.html and type your html code inside
2. Open the file signature.html with your Internet Browser
3. Copy the output and paste into the signature section of Gmail

Answer (score 0):

I've made a chrome extension to help do exactly this. It overlays an HTML code editor on top of Gmail and injects your HTML email directly into the gmail compose window. You can even save your snippets and reuse them as you'd like!

Give it a shot here: Google Chrome Web Store - [HTML Inserter For Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-inserter-for-gmail/enbnalopmjbaoabgclmajcnjamoglodp?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Comment: But with this, you'd have to edit the signature every time you write an email, right?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal - It lets you save the signature as a 'snippet' that you can reuse. Every time you send an email, you'll have to click "Snippets", then select it, but you won't have to re-paste the code.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I set up a "snippit" and then inserted it into an email, from the email I copied it and then pasted into the signature field that did accept the snippit perfectly as a signature that comes up whenever the signature is called by GMail. I have repeated the process for everyone in the company and it works perfectly.

Comment: Or, for firefox, there is this: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/7757 although I haven't tried it.