# How can I include HTML code in my Gmail signature?

Tags: gmail, email-signature

How can I include HTML code in my Gmail signature?

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it understandable but it was very hard to make sense of. I suggest you edit it again to clarify exactly what your issue is.

Comment: simply  I want used html code in g mail Signature

Comment: Do you know how to set your signature in Gmail or write HTML code?

Comment: Yes I know  how I create signature . and also html code

Comment: Do you know how to write HTML code?

Comment: I believe it has already been answered here - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18533/insert-html-markup-into-gmail-signature

Comment: I came up with an approach I haven't seen elsewhere: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92327/122349 (Basically use Chrome Dev Tools to manipulate the HTML in the textarea)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very easy to have HTML code in Gmail signature, because I just did it.

Render your html code in browser and copy what you want to put into signature, then go to the Gmail setting and paste.

Than everything is OK.