# Image beside text in Gmail signature?

Tags: gmail, images, html, email-signature

I found here how to copy an HTML signature to a Gmail address: [Insert HTML markup into Gmail signature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18533/insert-html-markup-into-gmail-signature)

I would like to get something like this:(image is hosted on a server):

[image]

However, I did not manage to align the image left of the text with the Rich Text editor. Is this possible? That's what I managed so far:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create customized HTML table at: **[https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)**

[image: 2]]

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/heRClds.jpg?1">
</td>

<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>

<td>

Aerys II Targaryen<br/>
<b>House of Targaryen</b> - Dragonstone<br/>
<a href="https://i.imgur.com/CTpv3kp.jpg">no-internet-in-westeros.edu</a>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

and then copy/paste this code to the signature box by force:

- first, right-click on the signature box and select **Inspect**
  [image]

- then right-click on the highlighted div and select **Edit as HTML**
  [image]

- paste your HTML code between div tags and click into signature box again when done and press **<kbd>`SPACE`</kbd>** key otherwise code won't be accepted as input
  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a way how to solve this. Go to Google Docs, create a table:

[image]

Customize the border of the table:

[image]

One can copy this in the Gmail signature:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Wow, make all kinds of HTML code... that will send most of your mail right to the virus filter.

Just make an image of the whole thing and insert that.

Comment: Would be nice if the links in the signature are clickable. And if you add an image to your mail its not plain text anyway.

Comment: Have you tried your solution ? I did and Gmail complains that the signature is too long