# Getting rid of - - at gmail

Tags: gmail, email-signature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to not have the new gmail Signature add “--” before it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/is-there-a-way-to-not-have-the-new-gmail-signature-add-before-it)

How can I get rid of `--` at gmail's signature?

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3676#section-4.3 *There is a long-standing convention in Usenet news which also commonly appears in Internet mail of using "-- " as the separator line between the body and the signature of a message.  When generating a Format=Flowed message containing a Usenet-style separator before the signature, the separator line is sent as-is.*

Answer (score 11):

Head over to [Labs](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/?shva=1#settings/labs) and enable "Signature Tweaks"

> Places your signature before the quoted text in a reply, and removes the "--" line that appears before signatures.